# Use dict values as kwargs in function that have not compatible signature

Tags: python, function, dictionary, signature

I have a single structure that is being used as a limit factor for multiple generators.

The structure looks like this:

```
my_dict = {
  "a": {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 1,
  },
  "b": {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 2,
  },
}
```

And generators looks like this:

```
def gen_1(low: float, high: float):
    return random.uniform(low, high)

def gen_2(lower_bound: float, higher_bound: float):
    return random.uniform(lower_bound, higher_bound)
```

Generators have a different signature and cannot be changed (3rd party libraries).

For me it is really convenient to use kwargs and when it comes to the `gen_1()` I can do something like this:

```
value = gen_1(**my_dict["a"])
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use the second generator in the same fashion and am forced to explicitly set these arguments:

```
value = gen_2(lower_bound=my_dict["a"]["low"], higher_bound=my_dict["a"]["high"])
```

Is it possible to somehow map these key values 'on the fly' while using kwargs?

Comment: You could try unpacking the values if the functions always expect the arguments in the same order, eg *dict['a'].values()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility could be to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and unpacking its output:

```
from operator import itemgetter

gen_1(*itemgetter('low', 'high')(my_dict['a']))

gen_2(*itemgetter('low', 'high')(my_dict['a']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known set of keys that you would need to change between, it would be straightforward to set up a function to modify the dictionary as you pass it into kwargs. Funny enough as it is, I'd use a dictionary to do this. Suppose you have your original keys A/B/C, but for gen2 you know they need to be a/b/c, you could set up a 'translator' dictionary as:

```
gen2translator = {"A":"a","B":"b","C":"c"}
```

Once you construct this, you could then use it in a function to modify the dictionary. Something akin to:

```
def Gen2Translator(dictionary_in,translator=gen2translator):
     for key in translator: 
          original_key = key
          new_key = translator[key]
          dictionary_in[new_key] = dictionary_in[original_key]
          del dictionary_in[original_key]
     return dictionary_in
```

This does come with some caveats, though. Primarily, you'd need to add in a check to manage any keys that don't appear in your original dictionary that you've listed in your translator. Secondly, you could clean up the code more if you used the .pop() method, as this removes the item and returns a value at the same time. However, the above logic should get you close enough. Using a function like this, you could then pass in the same dictionary to your gen2 as:

```
value = gen_2(**Gen2Translator(my_dict["a"]))
```

TLDR; make a dictionary of key_original:key_new pairs for your gen2 function, set up a new function to swap these keys into the original set (while preserving the original value), drop the original key, and then pass this new dictionary to gen2. Cheers!

Comment: Suggestion: `for key in list(translator.keys())` should just be `for key in translator:`. Using `.keys` isn't necessary just to iterate over the keys, and if you do use it, there is no point in creating a `list` out of it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah yes good point, old habit. I'll update the code accordingly